# Good references on the convergence of Markov chains with countably infinite state space

Tags: probability, reference-request

I'm looking for good references on the convergence time of a Markov chain with a countably infinite state space. Most books deal with finite state Markov chains, whose theory is well established. There are also books explaining general (i.e. continuous) state space Markov chains, but it is hard to find detailed results about countable Markov chains (probably due to my lack of knowledge). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found
Asmussen's book [*Applied Probability and Queues*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387002111) useful.

(It may also be available as a PDF if you google around for it; try adding "filetype:pdf" into your search query.)

Comment: Thanks for your pointer. The books seems to be focused on queuing thoery, though, and the treatment of the convergence rate is brief. I wonder if there are books which address the convergence of countable Markov chains more deeply.